# Regex to insert newlines into large block of text at specific locations

Tags: regex

I have a rather large text file that has a bunch of missing newlines, meaning that it's a mess. I need to break it up into appropriate lines.

The text looks something like this now:

```
12345 This is a chunk 23456 This is another chunk 34567 This is yet another chunk 45678 This is yet more chunk 56789 Yet another piece of text
```

I need a regex that will insert a newline (CR/LF pair) before each group of five digits, resulting in something like this:

```
12345 This is a chunk 
23456 This is another chunk 
34567 This is yet another chunk 
45678 This is yet more chunk 
56789 Yet another piece of text
```

It can insert one before the first group of digits or not; that I can deal with.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: No, the Research one is very good - I have been using it a lot of late.  The one *I* am thinking of was from 2 yrs or so ago.  R Harvey or Bill the Lizard (or maybe Shog) was periodically posting self answers (IRC) one of which amounted to *What are the minimums expected of SO users* (though that could be just a part of a broader post).  In it, it was explicitly stated users are expected to know how to program and use the debugger.  There was much more including some stuff about research and such but the other parts were what I would like to get a hold of.

Comment: I have in the past combed thru Harvey's catalog of MSO posts to no avail, but it could actually be some one else's or it could be on MSE. I goggled some keywords on MSE earlier to no avail.  Whomever wrote it was posting one or 2 good "manifestos" each week and editing/bumping others for a long time.  Maybe That Guy on MSE that is good at finding other posts could find it (forget his name as I havent been to MSO in a long time)

Comment: @Plutonix: I combed Harvey's as well, and couldn't find it. I still think I know the one you're thinking about, and will keep looking. It was more of a list of what you should do (but not [Jon Skeet's blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Very simple (but not as "flashy" as possible, since I'm too lazy to use lookaheads):

```
s/(\d{5})/\r\n\1/gs
```

Comment: You probably want \r\n since the OP wants CR/LF

Comment: @cletus: It might depend on the programming language but Perl and Python replace \n by \r\n on Windows.

Comment: Noted, and modified as requested.

Answer (score 7):

```
s/(?<=\D)(\d{5})(?=\D|$)/\n\1/g
```

#### On "\n" vs. "\r\n"

It might depend on the programming language at hand but Perl and Python replace `\n` by `\r\n` on Windows therefore it is a mistake in this case to replace `\n` by `\r\n` in the above regex.

Comment: Thanks, J.F. Your solution works also (with the correction to \r\n mentioned in the comments to cmartin above).

Comment: It totally depends on the regex engine you're using. In Perl/Python you're absolutely right. I was doing some 1-off cleanup of some files to be imported, and was using RegExBuddy; it's flavor of regex needed \r\n.

Thanks again.